# Wrap text gridExtra

Tags: r, word-wrap, gridextra

I want to wrap some columns containing text, but my code produces not what I want:

```
b <- c("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua","Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum"," Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"," Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua"," At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua"," Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"," Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua", " Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua","Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi"," Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat")
df <- data.frame(A = seq(1:length(b)), B = b, C = tolower(gsub("[[:space:]]|[[:punct:]]", "", b)))

library(gridExtra)
library(grid) 
pdf("C:/path/file.pdf",width=100,height=20)
d <- data.frame(B = sapply(lapply(df$B, strwrap, width=100), paste, collapse="\n"), C = sapply(lapply(df$C, strwrap, width=100), paste, collapse="\n"), df[,-c(2,3)])
grid.table(d)
```

I want the columns `B` and `C` being 7 inches wide and the remaining columns attached to the plot without word wrap. I don't understand the width of lapply `lapply(df$B, strwrap, width=100)`. Is it in inches? 
The word wrap doesn't work for column `C`. Is there a function to soecify a line break position after x characters for strwrap?

Comment: your example doesn't seem correct (d has only one column 1:7)

Comment: I edited it. I put `data.frame` around.

Comment: contrast `strwrap("this is long",8)` and `strwrap("this_is_long",8)`: if the words have no white space, strwrap has no effect.

Comment: Is there no parameter in strwrap to do the line break after a certain number of characters?